Object of type 'Mono.Cecil.TypeReference' cannot be converted to type 'System.Type' after upgrading Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions
In a dotnet 8 Azure Function project, I have to upgrade the package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions due to a vulnerability, from 4.0.0 to 4.5.0.
Upgrading this package causes a strange error, the gist of it is:
Object of type 'Mono.Cecil.TypeReference' cannot be converted to type 'System.Type'
Here is the full error message with all the details:
Error (active)      System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'Mono.Cecil.TypeReference' cannot be converted to type 'System.Type'.
   at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
   at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(StackAllocedArguments& stackArgs, ReadOnlySpan`1 parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at MakeFunctionJson.TypeUtility.ToReflection(CustomAttribute customAttribute) in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/TypeUtility.cs:line 106
   at MakeFunctionJson.TypeUtility.GetResolvedAttribute(ParameterDefinition parameter, CustomAttribute customAttribute) in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/TypeUtility.cs:line 67
   at MakeFunctionJson.ParameterInfoExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<ToFunctionJsonBindings>b__1(CustomAttribute a) in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/ParameterInfoExtensions.cs:line 32
   at System.Linq.Utilities.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`3.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Utilities.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`3.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.ToList()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MakeFunctionJson.ParameterInfoExtensions.ToFunctionJsonBindings(ParameterDefinition parameterInfo) in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/ParameterInfoExtensions.cs:line 29
   at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.<>c.<ToFunctionJson>b__6_0(ParameterDefinition p) in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/MethodInfoExtensions.cs:line 66
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.SparseArrayBuilder`1.ReserveOrAdd(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Concat2Iterator`1.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.ToFunctionJson(MethodDefinition method, String assemblyPath) in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/MethodInfoExtensions.cs:line 65
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.GenerateFunctions(IEnumerable`1 types)+MoveNext() in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/FunctionJsonConverter.cs:line 140
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryGenerateFunctionJsons() in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/FunctionJsonConverter.cs:line 194
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryRun() in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/FunctionJsonConverter.cs:line 87
Error generating functions metadata
    Teleclaim.API   C:\Users\bd57031\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\4.5.0\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets  32 

Also, clicking on the error message in Visual Studio, takes the cursor to this piece inside the: [UserFolder]\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\4.5.0\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets :
<GenerateFunctions
  TargetPath="$(TargetDir)bin\$(TargetFileName)"
  OutputPath="$(TargetDir)"
  UserProvidedFunctionJsonFiles="@(UserProvidedFunctionJsonFiles)"
  FunctionsInDependencies="$(FunctionsInDependencies)"
  TaskAssemblyDirectory="$(_FunctionsTasksDir)"/>

I wonder if anyone has had a similar experience upgrading this package and overcoming this issue?

Please provide your function code and .csproj

The issue could due the version compatibility issues between Package version, SDKs and function core tools or due to the changes in how metadata is being generated or handled in package version you are installing, refer to the similar issue.
In case of in-process model projects that uses version 4.5.0 of  Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions, should use 4.0.6517 or later versions of Function Core Tools.
Uninstall theexisting version of Function core tools and install latest version.
Command to install Core tools:
npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true

Delete the %LocalAppData%\AzureFunctionsTools folder and restart Visual Studio.

Clean and Rebuild the Project.

I have created a .NET 8.0 Azure function.
Add "FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED": "1", in local.settings.json.
local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED": "1",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}

.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

